# Construct Page Reference for a Survey Response Page

Tags: pagereference, notification, survey, response

I am attempting to use a custom notification to send a survey reminder to a Salesforce user.   I cannot figure out how to designate the page reference argument to the flow action that generates the notification.   The URL I am trying to imbed in the notification is https://mindful-unicorn-rlfsuv-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/survey/runtimeApp.app?invitationId=0Ki5f000000cBiU&surveyName=employee_sentiment&UUID=dc196d43-f143-46e4-9b94-01965bea570b, which is a link to a specific survey response page built using standard salesforce surveys (SurveyInvitation.InvitationLink). Naively using this URL as a page reference results in an unhandled fault, with the error message "Error Occurred: Invalid parameter value for: targetPageRef.."

Currently I am using the Target ID option in the notification, which generates a link to the survey invitation record -- not bad, but what I really want is a link to the corresponding response page, a web page.

I found various, pretty much [unfathomable documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) regarding how to construct a page reference.  I am hoping someone has already deciphered this.

thanks in advance for any assistance.

[image: screenshot of flow][image: detail of send notification action]

Comment: if you provided the screenshots of the flow you are using of what you have tried so far, it would easier to help you

Comment: attached screen shots..  What I had tried so far is already in there.  thanks for the advice

Comment: Could please post screenshot displaying where you input the page reference and the screenshot of error message "Error Occurred: Invalid parameter value for: targetPageRef.."?